# Is there a way to get the name of a workbook in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

There is a worksheet.title method but not workbook.title method. Looking in the documentation there is no explicit way to find it, I wasn't sure if anyone knew a workaround or trick to get it.

Comment: Can you give us some more context?  The workbook name is the filename.  So, since you either have to create a new workbook and specify a filename to save, or you are opening an existing workbook by specifying the filename, I can't think of any situation where you would not already have that information.

Comment: @David put far more eloquently than me I think

Comment: @David hm true... I have the user inputting the whole directory for the workbook, so i could extract it out of that. I was just wondering if there was something easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workbook doesn't really have a name - normally you'd just consider it to be the basename of the file it's saved as... *slight update* - yep, even in VB WorkBook.Name just returns "file on disk.xls"

Comment: Interesting. I'll just extract it from the user's input when they give the filename.

Comment: @ZakParks: Note that Python's `os.path` module comes with stuff to make it easy to extract the basename. For example, if `p` contains the full path, then the basename (including extension) is `os.path.basename(p)`. If the extension is always a fixed number of characters (such as `.xlsx`) you can strip it off with `os.path.basename(p)[:-5]`. If the extension can be `.xls` or `.xlsx`, you could do `os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(p)[0])`. And to make it all less verbose, your import can be of the form `from os.path import basename, splitext`.

Comment: @JohnY Nice! Much simpler then the loop i was using, thanks a ton!

Comment: @0andriy - depends on what you mean by "work". Your file's basename would be `.xlsx`, and it would have no extension.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem myself, John Clements' answer that this property doesn't exist was useful!

I found what I think to be a good solution, while this property isn't there. At the point of loading the file, instead of giving the file name as a string, first set the file name in a veriable and then load the file using this veriable. You can then amend the workbook class you get from loading the workbook with a new property and you can set this property to the file name veriable. This way, no matter how far down you pass this class inside functions, you have the file name without having to pass it seperatly.

e.g.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

file = 'file_name_here.xlsx'

wb = load_workbook(file, read_only = False)

wb.name = file
```

Would definetly be handy if OpenPyXL implamented this feature and had it so that wb.save() worked without an input perameter. (I've not yet done a PR to an open source project yet and don't feel confident enough yet so I don't mean to complain)

Not sure if this should be a seperate answer or should have been a comment on Jon's answer but here we are.